# Which one is a good practice ? combine the authentication as one function for administrators and users , or separate it?

Tags: php

i have a authentication function to validate administrator login, im thinking to combine it with user authentication as it require just simple logic, but is it a good practice ? and is it in the future/later easy to manage it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very good practice. For the long term it gives you much more control over your application. You may want to do some research on ACL (Access Control List).

You basically define some roles - you could store those in a database table. Let's use a fictive ACL library and say you have 5 roles:

```
$acl = new Acl;
$acl->addRole('guest');
$acl->addRole('user', 'guest');
$acl->addRole('staff', 'user');
$acl->addRole('admin', 'staff');
$acl->addRole('root', 'admin');
```

You can already see: user gets to do everything a guest can do + some more. Staff can do everything a user can do + some more. Admin (...) etc.
Now let's define some resources:

```
$acl->addResource('website');
$acl->addResource('api', 'website');
$acl->addResource('cms', 'api');
```

Similar inheritance going on here.
Then assign some permissions:

```
$acl->allow('root', '*');
$acl->allow(array('admin', 'staff'), 'cms');
$acl->allow('user', 'api');
$acl->allow('guest', 'website');
```

See the possibilities already? A regular guest can only see a webpage. A logged in user can see the same webpage but with some additional content - like other users being logged in - and apply for an access token to access the API. Admin & staff can do all that too, but they can also access the CMS. You can add more resources and rules: staff is allowed to edit content, but only admin can edit, publish & delete content.

```
<?php if ($acl->isAllowed('delete', $role)) { ?>
    <button name="delete">Delete</button>
<?php}?>
```

So yes: it is good practice to use 1 strong authentication system for all your users - no matter their user level. Through ACL you then control who can do what, when and where.